Translation for countries and timezones in the countries-and-timezones npm package
I'm using this package: https://github.com/manuelmhtr/countries-and-timezones.
I’m working on a React registration app that includes fields for users to select their country and timezone.
I want to translate all country names into the user’s preferred language, for example, translating 'China' to '中国' for Chinese users.
Is there a package that supports this type of translation, or do I need to manually translate all fields within my React app?
